# Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in rails 3.1.0.rc5 when connecting to gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp

When ever time i try sending notifications in my rails app i get the following error

```
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535-5.7.1 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at                   
):
  app/models/friendship.rb:6:in `send_request'
  app/controllers/friends_controller.rb:21:in `make_friendship'
```

my development.rb mail config settings is

```
  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  # Gmail SMTP server setup
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
        :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
        :enable_starttls_auto => true,
        :port => 587,
        :domain => '@example.com',
        :authentication => :plain,
        :user_name => 'user@gmail.com',
        :password => 'secret'
  }
```

Comment: This is working for me in development, but it does fail in production, any idea?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have this and it works for me:

```
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port                 => 587,
    :user_name            => "name@example.com",
    :password             => 'password',
    :authentication       => "plain",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Comment: tried it out i get this error message now `Net::SMTPServerBusy (421 Server busy, too many connections
`

Comment: Sorry, but that's not enough info to give you more help. I would try a different SMTP server to see if it's just gmail that's having problems. Something like Sendmail.

Comment: Is it possible to read mails from my company mail server with NET::SMTP. I tried but got Net::SMTPAuthenticationError. Any suggestions

Comment: My problem was that I only put the "**name**" part in the value of `user_name`, not the full email address "**name@example.com**". Having put the full email address, the email sent!

Comment: some tutorials show a `:domain => "mydomain.com"` ... Everything else i had matched this answer. Once I removed that, it worked.

Answer (score 12):

Login to the account you're using in your browser then visit this page:

http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

This gives you a 10 minute window to login with the app you want to let access your account. Go back to your Rails app and make it send an email, after that everything should work.

Comment: Lifesaver! This is just what I needed.

Comment: my issue was in development, had to enable this setting here for the sender acct: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: I first turned on this setting google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps and then http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha, after that send email from my app but still facing this error :(
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (534-5.7.14

Comment: please can you take a look

Answer (score 7):

I have a similar configuration that works fine but once in a while I get this error and I suspect that it is because Google mark the account as potentially abusive for some reason, too fast logins etc (each time a mail is sent).

You can make it work again by manually login via web interface and type the CAPTCHA. If this happens often I would probably think about using some other solution, like using an own MTA or at least an local MTA between Rails and gmail capable of sending multiple mails without relogin. In that case you may even deliver the mail yourself without going thru gmail, just make sure to setup proper SPF records etc.

Answer (score 4):

you are missing the link in the error message! :)

```
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535-5.7.1 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=14257
```

Thus for details see: https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=14257

- Make sure that you've entered your full email address (e.g. username@gmail.com)
- Make sure your mail client isn't set to check for new mail too often. If your mail client checks for new messages more than once every 10 minutes, your client might repeatedly request your username and password.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem: it worked from my desktop (in development environment), but it failed from production environment (a server in Sweden...).
You have to login into your gmail account and check the emails if Google has prevented the sign-in attempt.