# Sending an email in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, smtp, gmail-imap

I'm trying to send an email using Ruby on Rails but I get the error:

> Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in UsersController#create
>
> 535-5.7.1 Username and Password not accepted.

---

But the username and password combination is correct. I've gone through it multiple times.

This is my setup_mail.rb:
I changed the username, password and domain for privacy reasons.

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = { 
    :address            => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port               => 587,
    :domain             => "mydomain.com",
    :authentication     => "plain",
    :user_name          => "myname",
    :password           => "mypw",
    :enable_starttls_auto   => true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your username has to be

```
:user_name => "myname@mydomain.com"
```

For gmail the domain is required.

Comment: And I think you have to use TLS for your authentication, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this link is helpful

https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora/issues/1539

http://www.manu-j.com/blog/wordpress-exim4-ubuntu-gmail-smtp/75/

[Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in rails 3.1.0.rc5 when connecting to gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956018/netsmtpauthenticationerror-in-rails-3-1-0-rc5-when-connecting-to-gmail)

thanks

sameera