# Rails 3 mailer not working and not logging any errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I have tried all kinds of configurations but still I can't send an email in my development environment from rails.

I installed mailutils to try this from the command line and it worked, I received the email (in spam of course): echo test | mail -s Subject user@example.com

Here's my config:

```
# Don't care if the mailer can't send
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true # still no logs about emails

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true # I can't believe I have to add this option. Does it even exist? I found it on google.
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => 587,
  :domain => "gmail.com",
  :authentication => :login,
  :user_name => "some_user@gmail.com",
  :password => "abc123",
}
```

And here's the code in the mailer:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "root@ubuntu"

  def test_email
    Rails.logger.debug 'test_email'
    mail(:to => 'user@example.com', :subject => "testing rails")
  end
end
```

The controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    UserMailer.test_email
  end
end
```

development.log:

```
[2012-03-01 18:26:45.859] DEBUG  [bb44dee806d73eb60ab3ae16297f5c02] [127.0.0.1] [GET] [http://myapp:3000/] test_email
[2012-03-01 18:26:45.888]  INFO  [bb44dee806d73eb60ab3ae16297f5c02] [127.0.0.1] [GET] [http://myapp:3000/]   Rendered user_mailer/test_email (1.6ms)
[2012-03-01 18:26:45.898]  INFO  [bb44dee806d73eb60ab3ae16297f5c02] [127.0.0.1] [GET] [http://myapp:3000/]   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (1.1ms)
[2012-03-01 18:26:46.815]  INFO  [bb44dee806d73eb60ab3ae16297f5c02] [127.0.0.1] [GET] [http://myapp:3000/] Completed 200 OK in 455ms (Views: 112.4ms)
```

I also tried using the console:

```
root@ubuntu:/srv/www/myapp# rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.1)
irb(main):001:0> UserMailer.test_email
=> #<Mail::Message:32110400, Multipart: false, Headers: <To: user@example.com>, <Subject: testing rails>, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: text/html>>
```

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html has an example for GMail configuration. It uses 'plain' for the authentication attribute, have you tried it?

Comment: yes I tried it and nothing happened. Without any logs this isn't going to work. Everything else in the request is logged correctly

Comment: What does the code that invokes the mailer look like?

Comment: @FrederickCheung I added the controller to my post

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
  UserMailer.test_email
```

Just creates a `Mail::Message` object. To actually send an email you need to do

```
  UserMailer.test_email.deliver
```

(or starting with rails 4.2 `deliver_now` / `deliver_later`)

Comment: Ok this is embarrassing.. Thanks

Comment: Ow My God! I spent 3 hours, totally forgot about this method! Thanks

Comment: Note for rails 5: DEPRECATION WARNING: `#deliver` is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5. Use `#deliver_now`

Answer (score 9):

Regarding logging errors:

Just figured out by tinkering that a bang method counterpart exists for deliver, which throws an exception. Can be pretty useful to check if you just misspelled your username or password, or you just have some misconfigured settings.

`UserMailer.test_email.deliver!`

Answer (score 1):

An updated answer for Rails 4.2 would be:

```
UserMailer.test_email.deliver_now!
```

The exclamatory mark is to raise an exception if there are any errors.

Comment: Exclamation also adds implied urgency :)

Comment: `deliver_now!` Delivers an email _without_ checking perform_deliveries and raise_delivery_errors, so use with caution. http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActionMailer/MessageDelivery.html#method-i-deliver_now-21

Answer (score 0):

If you suspect it's your settings, try taking out the :domain. It worked for me a while ago.( [Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in rails 3.1.0.rc5 when connecting to gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956018/netsmtpauthenticationerror-in-rails-3-1-0-rc5-when-connecting-to-gmail/7042684#7042684) )

But I don't see a :body option in the `mail` function. Perhaps that's the issue. Try sending it from rails console and see what happens. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#method-i-mail