# How do I send an email from Rails using Gmail?

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, ruby-on-rails-5, mailer

I'm using Rails 5 and trying to send out some emails from my dev machine using Gmail as a relay.  I have this mailer file, app/mailers/user_notifier.rb

```
class UserNotifier < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: RAILS_FROM_EMAIL

  # send notification email to user about the price
  def send_notification(user_notification, crypto_price)
    puts "user notification: #{user_notification.id}"
    @user = user_notification.user
    @crypto_price = crypto_price
    threshhold = user_notification.buy ? 'above' : 'below'
    puts "user: #{@user.email} currency: #{@user.currency}"
    mail( :to => @user.email,
    :subject => sprintf(Constants::USER_NOTIFICATION_SUBJECT, crypto_price.crypto_currency.name, threshhold, PriceHelper.format_price(user_notification.price, @user.currency) )  )
  end
```

And then I send the email from a Sidekiq worker like so

```
UserNotifier.send_notification(user_notification, price).deliver
```

Although I don't see any errors in my logs, the email is never delivered (I have checked my spam folder to verify this).  Below is my config/environments/development.rb file.

```
  # ActionMailer Config
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
     address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
     port:                 587,
     domain:               'mybox.devbox.com',
     user_name:            'myusertest1',
     password:             'myuser99999',
     authentication:       'plain',
     enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  # change to true to allow email to be sent during development
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
```

Any ideas what could be going wrong or how I can troubleshoot this further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in Rails 5, the proper syntax would be

```
UserNotifier.send_notification(user_notification, price).deliver_now
```

...and use full email as username.

Comment: Gave that a whirl but nothin' doing.  Still don't receieve any emails.

Comment: Added an edit. I use gmail as a relay and I used full email as username. Worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks, I ahdn't thought of that.  I'm still not getting the emails (even in spam) -- is there a way I can get a trace of what's going on?  The log files don't seem to reveal much.

Comment: Try adding a bang ('!') to the end of deliver_now (ex. UserMailer.test_email.deliver_now!) this should give you a runtime error if something isn't quite right. My source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16410194

Comment: @Dave so I built a new app and a test mailer. I copied your settings changing the username and password to my account (I tried the username alone and not the full email). I opened rails console and called on the mailer directly using deliver_now! and it went through. Can you test it in console and return the results?

Comment: @Dave hey bud. Did you ever get your thing to ding?

Comment: I did!  After applying your deliver_now! option, I saw that Gmail was throwing an authentication error, which turned out to be the fact that I have to enable the "Allow less secure apps to access your account" option.  After turning that on, all went through.

Comment: @Dave Awesome! Glad to hear.