# Resend confirmation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, smtp

i got error with resend confirm mail on my gmail:

Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in Devise::ConfirmationsController#create
534-5.7.14

```
def check_auth_response(res)
  unless res.success?
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError, res.message
  end
end
```

/development.rb

```
    ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
      address:            "smtp.gmail.com",
      port:               587,
      domain:             "localhost:3000",    
      user_name:          '...@gmail.com',
      password:           '...',
      authentication:     "login",
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check your username and password. Set authentication to "plain". Alternatively, you may have to bypass Google's security captcha on the following link (as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956018/netsmtpauthenticationerror-in-rails-3-1-0-rc5-when-connecting-to-gmail)): http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
      address:            "smtp.gmail.com",
      port:               587,  
      user_name:          'username@gmail.com',
      password:           'password',
      authentication:     "plain",
      enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
```

Comment: no it's not working , i read some other similar questions, and your advise not help me. But i also not know how to make confirm for all gmail accounts.

Comment: Try allowing "less secure apps" on your gmail. https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/security. Let me know if it works.

Comment: oh i'm russian redneck, which overflow with self-confidence, i incorrect read information about LESS secure, sorry for your borrowed time

Comment: It's no problem. To be certain, permitting "less secure apps" worked for you right? So that I can update my answer and help more people more easily. Thanks.